# Setting unique key in for:each and for:Item

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

```
<template for:each={arrays} for:item="array">
                <li key= ?>
                    {array}
                </li>
  </template>
```

in Js file my 'arrays' is array of String 
arrays = ['first', 'seconds', 'third'];

how do i create unique key?

Also, I am fairly new to salesforce lightning web components, can somebody tell me why is there no variable declaration like: var, let, etc. in JS of LWC.

how do i write a for-loop in JS

```
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
        arr.push({
     Id: i,
        Name: this.arrays
       });
    }
```

Comment: Might be worth trying the [Learn to work with Javascript Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/learn-to-work-with-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot iterate over normal javascript simple array, it needs to be array of object.

[From Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_lists):

> Every item in a list must have a key. When a list changes, the
>   framework uses the key to identify each item so that it can rerender
>   only the item that changed. The key must be a string or a number, it
>   can't be an object. You can’t use index as a value for key. Assign
>   unique keys to an incoming data set. To add new items to a data set,
>   use a private property to track and generate keys.

You can quickly convert simple JS array into Array of Object by using a getter

```
  @track arrays = ['first', 'seconds', 'third'];

    get complexArray(){
        let arrayOfMap = [];

        this.arrays.forEach(function(element , index ){
            arrayOfMap.push({"Name":element, "Id":index});
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfMap));
        return arrayOfMap;
    }
```

And then your markup will iterate over the getter property.

```
<template for:each={complexArray} for:item="ele" key={ele.Id}  >
  {ele.Name} <br key={ele.Id}>

</template>
```

Playground Link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/CL3Ichlv/4/edit

**UPDATE:** Even if the documentation says, you cant' use index as a value of key, I found out that you can use it

```
<template>


<template for:each={arrays} for:item="ele" key={index}>
  <li key={index}>
      {ele}
  </li>

</template>

</template>
```

Js:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track arrays = ['first', 'seconds', 'third'];


}
```

Playground Link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/CL3Ichlv/8/edit

Comment: Not sure if it worked for you temporarily with key={index}, but it doesn't work any more. It might be that you didn't actually link the index becuase the template 'key' attribute is not a valid attribute - it should be for:index="index"

Answer (score 1):

For assigning unique key you can use multidimensional array.

html file:

```
<template>
<template for:each={mapObj} for:item="array">
                <li key= {array.key}>
                    {array.value}
                </li>
  </template>

</template>
```

JS file:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    names = [['first', 'seconds', 'third'], ['fourth', 'fifth']];
    @track mapObj = []
    connectedCallback() {
        for(let i=0; i< this.names.length; i++) {
            let obj = {key : i, value : this.names[i]}
            this.mapObj[i] = obj;
        }
        console.log("first list = " + JSON.stringify(this.mapObj[0].key));
        console.log("second list = " + JSON.stringify(this.mapObj[1].key));

    }

}
```

Output

```
first list = 0
second list = 1
```

I have declared mapObj and i variable in connectedCallback method.

> You must declare all variables. Use any of the var, let, or const
>   declarations in libraries or modules.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.security_locker_strict_mode

Playground link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/-ICV8fvj/2/edit

Answer (score -1):

You can get the attribute value and conditionally check. The below code shows how the for loop works in JS.

```
 var checkedRecord = component.get("v.yourList");



 var counterValue =0;
for(var i=0, i<listSize; i++){
if(checkedRecord[i].isChecked){
counterValue++;
}
```